# "On the run" in Latin

Tags: idiom, english

Is there a Latin equivalent to the English phrase "on the run" to indicate someone who's avoiding capture/recapture?  For example, "The prisoner is on the run."  Would something like *in fuga* be accurate, or would I need to settle for something like *Captivus effugit*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest phrase I could come up with is *in fuga*, which is quite literally "on the run".
There are [a number of classical attestations of this phrase](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=in+fuga%23).
Another good choice is the participle *fugiens*, possibly with a prefix *ef-* or *pro-*.

There is no Latin phrase that behaves exactly like "on the run", so you have to judge each context separately.
For "the prisoner is on the run" I would simply say *captivus profugit*.
For "while on the run, the prisoner slaughtered a dog", I would choose either *captivus profugiens canem necavit*, *captivus in fuga canem necavit*, or use two personal verbs like *captivus profugiebat et canem necavit*.
The choice is a matter of style and fluency.

Comment: So would you say that Latin favors constructs with a non-linking verb, thus `Captivus in fuga` would probably not be preferred?

Comment: @jpyams I'm not sure if it's a general tendency, but using *ille in fuga est* sounds weird, as opposed to *ille fugit*. I would say that "to be on the run" is best translated without *in fuga*, but it's safer not to draw too strong conclusions from it.

Comment: *mactāre* is a religious word, and the only way to understand it in this context is "sacrificed". You probably want the simplest option, which is *necāvit*. *in fugā* is a good suggestion, however - it's found repeatedly in Justinian's *Dīgesta* (*"aut sī servus in fugā est"*), and *"quī in fugā esse dīcitur"* confirms it's an established legal term.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I changed the verb as you suggested. Thanks!